# How can I add a link in accordion header alongside the toggle button using Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-accordion

I am trying to add a link in the `accordion-button` and make only the arrow clickable for collapsing

I added the following CSS to make the arrow clickable only. But struggling to make the link in the `accordion-button` work. I want the user to go to the location of the button not collapse.

```
.accordion-button {
    pointer-events: none;
}

.accordion-button::after {
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```

Here is what I have done. How can I make the arrow clickable only at the same time allow the `href` in the `accordion-button` clickable and take the user to the link?

```css
.accordion-button {
    pointer-events: none;
}

.accordion-button::after {
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
    
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header">
      <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
        <a href="/" class="btn btn-sm btn-link">Accordion Item #1</a>
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is shown by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
        <a href="/" class="btn btn-sm btn-link">Accordion Item #2</a>
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the second item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
        <a href="/" class="btn btn-sm btn-link">Accordion Item #3</a>
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="accordion-collapse collapse" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the third item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: FWIW your use of `<a href="/"` which navigates you to your site root from an accordion header is probably not a great choice from what users would expect here - try to not surprise your users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't nest anchors inside buttons. That's just a bad idea and is invalid HTML. [Buttons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) and [anchors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) have distinct purposes--buttons do actions and anchors (links) do navigation. They both have allowed content according to the HTML spec. You confuse your users and create accessibility problems if you nest them.

You also don't need to use heading elements for your accordion headers. You could wrap your links with them if you want that document structure.

- Use the accordion header as a flex container with items aligned to center
- Apply color and border to the accordion heading
- Remove color and shadow from the accordion heading button
- Optionally reduce button sizing by wrapping it in a div and justifying content space-between on the accordion header (see the second accordion heading for a demo). You may just let the accordion toggle target take all available space outside the link, though, for user convenience.

Notice that all this was done without any custom CSS. You'll want to get familiar with the Bootstrap docs so you know what it offers and don't duplicate effort.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <div class="accordion-header d-flex align-items-center bg-info-subtle border-bottom">
      <a href="/" class="text-nowrap mx-3">Accordion Item #1</a>
      <button class="accordion-button bg-transparent shadow-none" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne"></button>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is shown by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and
        hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="accordion-item">
    <div class="accordion-header d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center bg-info-subtle border-bottom">
      <a href="/" class="text-nowrap mx-3">Accordion Item #2</a>
      <div><button class="accordion-button collapsed bg-transparent shadow-none" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo"></button></div>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the second item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing
        and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I am struggling with removing the bottom border. I added `border-0` to the `accordion-button`. I can't identify what is adding the border

Comment: Answer updated. It wasn't border. It was shadow. Your browser's document inspector shows this.

Comment: Good answer.  FWIW I find Bootstrap tends to encourage these type of challenges for some reason.  I also am of the opinion that the use if `<i>` for icons instead of `<span>`  is a poor choice since the idiomatic text element `<i>` description is all about text re; "element represents a range of text that is set off from the normal text for some reason, " ref:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/i

Comment: What icons? I don't see the connection to this question or my answer. If you're referring to the accordion arrow, that is and should be in a button for accessibility.

Comment: No not in this question just a general statement re: bootstrap.  I should have stated that sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Add this css:

```
.accordion-header {
 position: relative;
}
.accordion-header .btn-link {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 99;
 top: 10px;
}
```

And step out the anchor tag outside the button tag and place just inside the "accordion-header" div:

```
<h2 class="accordion-header">
 <a href="/" class="btn btn-sm btn-link">Accordion Item #1</a>
 <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
  </button>
</h2>
```

Comment: Rarely is custom CSS the best strategy when working with Bootstrap, and absolute positioning is often troublesome. For mobile you're likely to see overlap with other elements.